# using inotify to monitor access to a file

Tags: files, inotify

I would like to have a trigger and when a particular file is accessed by some process, I would like to be notified (i.e. a script should be run). If I understand correctly, this could be achieved with `inotify`.

If I have a file `/foo/bar.txt` how would I set up `inotify` to monitor that file?

I am using Debian Wheezy with kernel 3.12 (my kernel has inotify support)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Gilles](https://superuser.com/users/42315/gilles) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/181543):

> Simple, using [inotifywait](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) (install your distribution's `inotify-tools` package):
>
> ```
> while inotifywait -e close_write myfile.py; do ./myfile.py; done
> ```
>
> This has a big limitation: if some program replaces `myfile.py` with a different file, rather than writing to the existing `myfile`, `inotifywait` will die. Most editors work that way.
>
> To overcome this limitation, use `inotifywait` on the directory:
>
> ```
> while true; do
>   change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create .)
>   change=${change#./ * }
>   if [ "$change" = "myfile.py" ]; then ./myfile.py; fi
> done
> ```

Comment: “It's simple but has two important issues: Events may be missed (all events in the loop) and initialization of inotifywait is done each time which makes this solution slower for large recursive folders.” – [Wernight](http://superuser.com/users/28782/wernight) (Fixing that post is on my todo list. Don't hold your breath.)

Answer (score 2):

The basic shell interface to inotify is [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) from [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki).

To monitor all accesses to a file:

```
inotifywait -mq --format '%e' /path/to/file |
while IFS= read -r events; do
  /path/to/script "$events"
done
```

Your script is called with a comma-separated list of simultaneous events, each time something happens to the file (read, write, close, …).

Comment: Same limitation applies here : editors like VIM replace the file with a different file. In monitor mode, `inotifywait` will not die silently but detect `MOVE_SELF`, then `ATTRIB`, then `DELETE_SELF` events on the first edit, then nothing on the subsequent edits.