# How to detect which process has used a file now or in the past

Tags: lsof, audit, fuser

This is a hypothetical question, not a problem I currently have.

How do you detect which process has used a file now *or in the past*?

To find out which process is accessing `filename` right now, `lsof filename` or `fuser filename` will do the work. But what if one wanted to know which processes accessed `filename` *in the last 24 hours*?

One could get away with this ugly (*) hack

```
while true; do fuser filename; sleep 1; done
```

and let it run for 24 hours in another term.
But is there actually a better system, without setting up a whole audit framework?

(*) not to mention that `fuser` could fail to detect the access if it took less than 1 sec...

Comment: A [search for `auditctl` here](/search?tab=Relevance&q=auditctl) reveals many possible duplicates.

Comment: Using your ugly hack, how do you store the process information, or are you just interested in a 'random' number ;-) ?

Comment: Related: [using inotify to monitor access to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134615/using-inotify-to-monitor-access-to-a-file).

Comment: @Lambert It was just an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your system has audit enabled, you can use that subsystem to audit access to specific files.

For example, to audit files opening (or trying to open) the `/etc/shadow` file, you can use the following rule:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S open -F path=/etc/shadow
```

Later on, you can then use this command to list the audited events corresponding to accesses to this file:

```
ausearch -f /etc/shadow
```

Note you need to be root to configure and query the audit system.

See the [auditctl(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) man page for more details on how to set rules and the [ausearch(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch) man page for details on how to query the audit logs.

If you don't have audit enabled, you should look up information on how to do that specific to your Linux distribution, since details will vary.